# Outerclass with its innerclass as an argument for the outerclass constructor

Tags: java, constructor, inner-classes, outer-classes

Im wondering if it is possible to create this object based on the code below or is it a cyclic dependency which cant be solved?

```java
public class A {
  private B b;

  public A(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  public class B {
    public B() {}
  }
  
}
```

I was provided with a class which looked like this and I cant find a way to initialize B or A. Its like and impossible cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you do with instance of `B` in `A`'s constructor is an assignment, then you could try using `null` at instantiation and then hand it a `B` instance:

```java
A a = new A(null);
A.B b = a.new B();
a.b = b;
```

the above requires `a.b` to be public, or you need to add a setter. But that looks bad to me, so perhaps you should make `B` class static, and by doing so it can be instantiated independently of `A`::

```java
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static class B {
        public B() {}
    }
}
```

and then

```java
A.B b = new A.B();
A a = new A(b);
```

Comment: Let's definitely highlight: __This is really bad code, and the first snippet is a horrible idea, it just proves a point, like a silly riddle, that you CAN do it__. The second snippet (make it `static`) is what you should be doing.

Comment: That's absolutely correct. There's also a high chance that the best approach would simply be refactoring that code and make it stink less.